# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Adb.Form1.hanteraKund' using a Controller on a Form

Tags: c#, field, non-static

I got some problem to initialize my Controller-class in my Form-class. It works fine in my console application but I get this error when I try to use it in my Form-application.

I understand what the error means, but not quite sure how to solve it.

This the beginning of my Form-class:

```
namespace Adb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HanteraKund hanteraKund = new HanteraKund();
        Controller controller = new Controller(hanteraKund);
```

My Controller:

```
namespace Adb
{
    class Controller
    {
        DBConnection Connection = new DBConnection();
        HanteraKund hanteraKund = new HanteraKund();

        public Controller (HanteraKund hanteraKund)
        {
            this.hanteraKund = hanteraKund;
        }
```

And finally my HanteraKund:

```
namespace Adb
{
    class HanteraKund
    {
        DBConnection Connection = new DBConnection();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400677/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the initialization into a constructor body instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private HanteraKund hanteraKund;
    private Controller controller;

    public Form1()
    {
        hanteraKund = new HanteraKund();
        controller = new Controller(hanteraKund);
    }
}
```

(You could leave `hanteraKund` initialized at the point of variable declaration if you wanted to. The important bit is that the `controller` initialization has to be in a constructor body, as otherwise it can't refer to `hanteraKund`.)