# Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, field

I can't find a solution for the following:

**Code:**

```
class ApiData

{ SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Peter\Documents   \db.sdf;");

SqlCeCommand cmd = null;
    SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
    public string code()
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText ="SELECT code FROM Charakter WHERE id=1";
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        string selected = rdr.GetString(0);
        conn.Close();
        return (selected);
    }
class Data{
  ApiData g= new ApiData();
    string vode = **g.code();**
}
```

**Error:**

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400677/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the field `static` which was giving this issue

```
//INITIALLY this field was non-static 
//public string ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBname;User Id=user_id;Password=password";

//Make this field static
public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBname;User Id=user_id;Password=password";
static SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: why connection string need to be STATIC?

Comment: @umeshsohaliya It's quite old answer, probably I might have done some hit and trial in one of our projects.

Answer (score 7):

The initial values for fields need to use constants, static fields/methods/properties, or new instances.  Instead, set it in your constructor:

```
class Data
{
    ApiData g;
    string vode;

    public Data()
    {
        g = new ApiData();
        vode = g.code();
    }
}
```

Comment: "The initial values for fields need to use constants" - it's not as restrictive as that; they can also reference static fields, methods or properties.  But the solution is right, +1.

Comment: thanks, I tried this before, but forgot the "string vcode;" line. I did too long nothing on c#^^