# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'SignalServer.connectionString' (CS0236)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use `SqlDependencyEx` it accepts the first argument as a connection string, if I use my DB connection string directly it works but I don't want to give it directly instead I want it to grab `DefaultConnection` using Configuration. but I'm getting this error

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'SignalServer.connectionString' (CS0236)

```
public class SignalServer : Hub
        {
            public readonly TestController _testController;
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            string connectionString = "";

            public SignalServer(TestController testController, IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                _testController = testController;
                connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            }

            public async void NotifyConnection()
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("TestBrodcasting", _testController.GetAllApps());
            }

            SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString);

        }
```

Update:

```
public class SignalServer : Hub
{
    public readonly TestController _testController;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public SignalServer(TestController testController, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _testController = testController;
        SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), "dbName", "tablename");
    }

    public async void NotifyConnection()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("TestBrodcasting", _testController.GetAllApps());
    }


    private void RegisterNotification()
    {
        sqlDependency.TableChanged += OnDataChange;
        sqlDependency.Start();
    }

    private void UnregisterNotification()
    {
        sqlDependency.Stop();
        sqlDependency.TableChanged -= OnDataChange;
    }

    private void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlDependencyEx.TableChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Dispose()
    {
        UnregisterNotification();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Is something unclear? You're trying to use `connectionString` when initializing `sqlDependency` and it's not static.

Comment: Hi Sam, does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015591/error-a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-pro) help you out?

Comment: @itsme86 I'm trying to use `SqlDependencyEx` it accepts the first argument as a connection string, if I use my DB connection string directly it works but I don't want to give it directly instead I want it to grab `DefaultConnection` using `Configuration`

Comment: You can keep the `SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency` declaration where it is, but move the initialization to the constructor after you set `connectionString`: `sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString);`

Comment: @KevinLamb not really it taking connection string directly I want it to grab from Configurations

Comment: @itsme86 can you show using my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString);
```

Move it inside the constructor instead:

```
SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency;
public SignalServer(TestController testController, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _testController = testController;
    connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    //Put it here
    sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString);
}
```

I don't know much about your design but you probably don't even need to save the connection string in the `connectionString` field. You might be able to just use it directly from the call to the `Configuration.GetConnectionString` method or the reference to the `Configuration` object you are storing.

Comment: if I use it directly gives this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SignalServer.Configuration' (CS0120)`

Comment: @Sam: Yes. You still need to do it within the constructor as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Sam Which line of code is causing that error?

Comment: @GaryStewart: I think his comment refers to the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @JuanR, I'm just wondering if there is a namespacing issue since he's using the a variable called "Configuration"

Comment: @GaryStewart: I thought so too but moving the initialization of `sqlDependency` to the constructor as shown in my answer should solve any non-static issues.

Comment: @JuanR I have updated my question even if I use your answer it still showing the same error.

Comment: @Sam: Your update is even worse. Just do what I put in my answer and remove the  line that tries to create the dependency outside of the constructor. the line that assigns `sqlDependency` **should only exist in the constructor, nowhere else**.

Comment: @GaryStewart the error is on `Configuration`

Comment: @JuanR I have updated my question again but now If I try to use `sqlDependency` in `RegisterNotification()` it is giving error `The name 'sqlDependency' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)`

Comment: @JuanR I got it thnx

Comment: @GaryStewart: Thank you for the correction on the variable. :-)