# Global object instances

Tags: c#, ogre

I'm new to c# and am looking to find how to call global object instances in my winform.

```
 namespace BeastEngine {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {

          private  Root mRoot = new Root();
          private  RenderWindow mWindow;
          private  SceneManager mgr = mRoot.CreateSceneManager(SceneType.ST_GENERIC);
          private Camera cam = mgr.CreateCamera("Camera");
```

Right now I'm calling my variables like so, but I'm getting various errors.

```
private void meshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Entity ent = mgr.CreateEntity("ninja", "ninja.mesh");
          mgr.RootSceneNode.CreateChildSceneNode().AttachObject(ent);
          cam.LookAt(ent.BoundingBox.Center);
      }
```

I want it so that all of my functions can use the one instance. Does anyone know of the proper way? I've googled everywhere.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: For future - consider first checking MSDN about error code that is part of the message. In your case it is [CS2036](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za(v=VS.80).aspx) which points to article that covers your case.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Singleton pattern.  If you search for that, you should get a lot more results.

Here's Microsoft's recommendation for [Implementing a Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance variable outside of the constructor

```
private Root mRoot = new Root();
private SceneManager mgr = mRoot.CreateSceneManager(SceneType.ST_GENERIC);
private Camera cam = mgr.CreateCamera("Camera");
```

You should instantiate this in your constructor.

```
private Root mRoot;
private SceneManager mgr;
private Camera cam;

public Form1()
{ 
    mRoot = new Root();
    mgr = mRoot.CreateSceneManager(SceneType.ST_GENERIC);
    cam = mgr.CreateCamera("Camera");
}
```

If you want to make sure it is known that this is only created at construction, you can make the variables `readonly`

[Here is an article on constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx)

[Look at Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400677/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property) for more information

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I go about doing that? @Justin Pihony

Comment: @user2040490 Updated my answer to give you the basic syntax

Comment: I have tried this already, but then it gives me an error whenever I call the instance ex. cam.position(0,0,0); - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user2040490 Sorry, I didnt see you were doing even more...I updated....do not do basic initialization outside of the constructor

Comment: on my initialization of cam, I get the error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: OK, now you really need to learn how to debug your own code. Most likely this is coming from somewhere in the CreateCamera method. Look at your callstack or add a debug breakpoint. Your question is answered, now you are talking about another error from something I have no knowledge of