# Is there SQL query through which i can directly dump data of a table into a text or csv file in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Is there SQL query through which i can directly dump data of a table into a text or csv file in C#?

Comment: You want to issue a single query to SQL and have the query itself create a text/csv file without any additional processing in C#?

Comment: This is too broad of a question

Comment: There are plenty of examples on line you can google in regards to converting a DataTable into CSV you could use SSIS as well ..you can also write your own method to handle this as well

Answer (score 1):

No. C# is not SQL, and vice versa. If you mean "how do I write a text file based on the results of a query?", it is easy enough.

If you use google to look for *C# SQL to text file*, the first hit is, you wouldn't guess, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000962/write-sql-info-to-a-txt-file)!

The main idea is you create your connection, define a reader based on your query, and use a streamwriter to create your file.

If you want other ways to export MSSQL data to files, you can have a look at [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ADO.Net or Entity Framework to query that table, then open a FileStream to output the data into a text/csv file.  There is not anything more direct and easy than this.

Comment: There are plenty of other ways to connect to databases than just ADO or EF ;)

Comment: LOL true but .... oh you know what i meant lol

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm just very frustrated that I have to talk to an Oracle database using stored procedures only, with DBA's and developers alike being afraid to use EF or even NHibernate :)

Comment: That stinks.  Stored procs with EF are fine.... not sure what the hold up is there.  Ahhh good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter ff = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    @"SELECT
                      firstName, 
                      lastName,
                      salary
                      FROM persons",
                    connection);
                connection.Open();

                ff.WriteLine("firstName,lastName,salary");  // header
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var rr = (IDataRecord)reader;
                    ff.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2:C2}",
                                                 rr.GetValue(0),
                                                 rr.GetValue(1),
                                                 rr.GetValue(2)                                                    
                                               )
                                );
                }                    
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

... on the other side you can build csv on db side and return as single value (varchar(max))

following example is for sqlsqrver

```
select cast((
    select 
        cc.clientId,
        ',', -- this is separator
        cc.clientName,
        ',',
        cc.birthdate,
        ',',
        cc.status,
        '
'  -- this new line
    from Clients cc
    for xml path('')

) as XML).value('.','varchar(max)')
```