# Thread using non-static method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to write a simple tool(it contains only one class), but I stuck on threads.
I dont know how to run thread with non-static method.

My code of windows form is something like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   //--Some methods here--//
   void login();
   void start();
   void refresh();

   //--Button events--//
   private void button1_Click()
   {
       //I want to start thread here
       //Something like Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(refresh));
       //t.Start();
   }
}
```

With timer this thread should call refresh() every x seconds, but timer isnt problem.
I'm getting error with thread:

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.
```

Comment: You didn't post the code that generates this compile error.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400677/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property

Answer (score 2):

In the button1_click() function, you can call your refresh method in another thread using lambda:

```
new Thread(
        () =>
        {
            refresh();
        }
        ).Start();
```

I'm pretty sure it will work well that way

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a timer for refreshing, then I do not think you need separate thread to refresh.

Or if you want to asynchronously invoke the refresh from timer_callback, you can create an Action delegate and call BeginInvoke on it.

```
Action ac = new Action(this.refresh);
ac.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Edit :
If you use System.Threading.Timer, it itself runs on another thread.  So starting thread from this timer call back is not suggested.  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm just learning programming so could you explain why it would be better to not use separate thread?
I wanted that some actions(they will take some time) will be executed on this thread every x seconds while other thread will be checking/doing something else.