# Why can't I initialize my Garage class?

Tags: c#, class

I have this `Car` class,

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public Car(): this ("", "") { }

    public Car(string name, string color)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Color = color;
    }
}
```

Also I have `Garage` class containing a collection of `Car`s.

```
public class Garage
    {
        public List<Car> CarList { get; set; }

        public Garage() { }

        public Garage(int carCount)
        {
            this.CarList = new List<Car>(carCount);
        }

        public Garage(params Car[] cars)
        {
            this.CarList = new List<Car>();
            foreach (Car car in cars)
               this.CarList.Add(car);
        }
    }
```

I tried to initialize an instance of a `Garage` in `Main()`,

```
Car car1 = new Car("BMW", "black");
Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "white");
Garage garage = new Garage(car1, car2);
```

I get an error, "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are no field initializers in the code you posted. Locate the line where the error is being reported, and post that line.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. I think you have problem elsewhere

Comment: Post your complete code please

Comment: Yes code looks fine for me

Comment: A side note, personally I wouldn't use empty strings in your default constructor. If you don't have values leave them as null.

Comment: Garage garage = new Garage(car1,car2). this is where i get an error. "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property "

Comment: Checked on my machide - works fine... so maybe just restart studio?

Comment: Ooor, may be you not showing us all what you got)))))

Comment: Questions must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce problem. Your code do not reproduce problem

Comment: restarted, still getting an error.

Comment: You are doing `Garage garage=new Garage(car1,car2)` inside a class right? You cannot do that. You should do that inside a constructor.

Comment: Dear try to re run your code. your code is completely fine.

Comment: Duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400677/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Comment: A common antipattern is to have settable collection properties. I'd change it to say `public List<Car> Cars { get; private set; }` otherwise your evil colleague will soon do this: `garage.Cars = null;`

Answer (score 1):

"Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields outside a method." 
Please check this page [ERROR page from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

So either make car object static  as;

```
    static Car car1 = new Car("BMW", "black");
    static Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "white");

    Garage garage = new Garage(car1, car2);
```

Or
declare it

```
     Car car1 = new Car("BMW", "black");
     Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "white");
     Garage garagel;
```

and then use inside any other method

```
    garage = new Garage(car1, car2);
```